# associate custom ID to ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview

Is it possible to use a hashmap in ArrayAdapter instanciation ?

my "regions" hashmap handles custom ID as keys : `Hashmap<ID,Value>`.

```
vRegions.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regions));
```

the problem here is that `ArrayAdapter` will call my hashmap's `toString()` which will print `value` and discard `ID`!

I want to be able to use that ID , is there any way to set it as `simple_list_item_1`'s `ID` so i can retreive it later inside onclick event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by passing a `hashmap` to my `ArrayAdapter` where keys are texts and values are the IDs.
I use the pressed item position to get the text then i search my `hashmap` for the associated ID.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend `ArrayAdapter` and add the logic there.

Comment: hello, we're not obliged to use hashmap, maybe there's a cleaner way out there to associate IDs to items ?

Comment: Create a class with a custom to string?